# Query on database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

In my project, I faces some situations that I need to query on same model  several times in the same view. (django model in this case as I am using django and postgresql).

The first approach for this may be filtering several times on the same model.

The another approach may be that I query on the model and fetched all the data and then saved that into a local variable. Then I can make filter on that variable several times.

which approach is most efficient I mean faster and which approach should I  go through.

Lets say I have a model named **People** and I can take the following two approaches:

(1)

```
active_peoples = People.objects.filter(active=True)
lazy_peoples = People.objects.filter(lazy=True)
inactive_peoples = People.objects.filter(active=False)
good_peoples = People.objects.filter(good=True)
bad_peoples = People.objects.filter(good=False)
```

(2)

```
peoples = People.objects.all()
lazy_peoples = peoples.filter(lazy=True)
inactive_peoples = peoples.filter(active=False)
good_peoples = peoples.filter(good=True)
bad_peoples = peoples.filter(good=False)
```

Which approach is faster??

Comment: Without a concrete example, this is far too vague to answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it' s totally depends on the datasets and your coding, see Django provides best filtering methods , which can filter your data in efficient way with less time constrain.

First test case:-

Suppose you have small dataset, then may be hitting database several times and fetching data may takes more time than fetching it once, stores in one variable and iterating through that. In this case better you go with storing data in one variable.

Second test case:-

Suppose you have large dataset,in this if you fetched data with djago filters every time may take less time than fetching it once, store in variable and after storing in variable iterating through it with less complexity algorithm.